# Set Banners for background Notification in iOS App

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app which when installed, is not automatically configured to show notifications getting to the app when it's in the background with banners (in the notification centre of the phone).

Is there something I can do about this in my code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, the default style for notifications is banner, therefore what  do you mean saying its not configured to show them with banners? ANyway you can't change the style, only the user can

Comment: Simply put, I open up the notifications center and it shows the settings are for sounds and tags. Not banners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set what kind of notifications you want your app to have.

See UIApplication:registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types. In your case you'll want to use UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge and 'OR' any of the others you want as well.

Comment: This seems to be right. Added the UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert type to the badge and sound that I have.